How to get a branch name in Azure DevOps when a tag is generated?
I want to get the branch name in a Azure pipeline. I can get it using:
- script: |
    echo "Original Source Branch: $(Build.SourceBranch)"
    BRANCH_NAME=${BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH#refs/heads/}
    echo "Branch Name: $BRANCH_NAME"
  displayName: 'Display source branch name'

But when I create a tag using:
git tag -a v1.0.1 -m "Release version 1.0.1"
git push origin v1.0.1 

the branch name is only the tag value as follows:

Branch Name: refs/tags/v1.0.1

Does anybody know how I can get the branch name when I created a tag?
I expected to get the branch name, but instead I get the tag value.

$(Build.SourceBranch) already returns the information you need, i.e. the branch of the triggering repo the build was queued for.
Just out of curiosity, why do you need to use a workaround to get the branch name when creating a tag?

Hi @Mina, the predefined variables Build.SourceBranch is the branch of the triggering repo the build was queued for. When the pipeline is triggered by a tag, the Build.SourceBranch should be refs/tags/tagname.  Do you mean that you need the branch name where the tag is created from?

The predefined variables Build.SourceBranch is the branch of the triggering repo the build was queued for. When the pipeline is triggered by a tag, the Build.SourceBranch should be refs/tags/tagname.
In my understanding, what you want is the branch name where the tag is created from. If it is, you can use the following powershell script to get the branch name.
- powershell:  |
    if ("$(Build.SourceBranch)" -like "refs/tags/*") {
        $tagName = "$(Build.SourceBranch)" -replace 'refs/tags/', ''

        # Get the commit hash of the tag
        $tagCommit = git rev-list -n 1 $tagName

        # Find the branch that contains the commit
        $BRANCH_NAME = git branch -r --contains $tagCommit | Select-String -Pattern 'origin/' | ForEach-Object { $_.Line -replace '.*origin/', '' } | Select-Object -First 1

        Write-Output "The tag $tagName was created from branch: $BRANCH_NAME"
    } else {
        $BRANCH_NAME = "$(Build.SourceBranch)" -replace 'refs/heads/', ''
        Write-Output "Branch Name: $BRANCH_NAME"
    }
  displayName: 'Display source branch name'


Test result:

